# Behat with Jenkins or Maven?

Tags: php, maven, jenkins, bdd, behat

Is Behat compatible with Jenkins and Maven.Can it be easily integrated? if not , then which BDD frameworks integrate well with Jenkins
Thanks

Comment: I might be wrong, but why would someone integrate maven with PHP BDD framework? I don't think problem is with maven + jenkins, but rather with maven + behat. Anyway, what is your programming language used? PHP?

Comment: yup the language is PHP!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get jenkins running your behat suite is to use a [shell script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-ShellScriptsandWindowsBatchCommands). Providing you've got a PHP environment setup on your jenkins host and the project dependancies installed through composer, you can specify a simple command such as `bin/behat`. This will run your behat feature suite, returning an error code if the suite fails. Jenkins should pick this up and fail your job too.

In my experience, having a specific profile in [behat.yml](http://docs.behat.org/guides/7.config.html#profiles) for specifying formatters and parameters is useful. As a result your command may look something like: `bin/behat --profile ci`

You can of course wrap these commands in something like maven or rake and instead of running a shell script in your jenkins job, you can invoke a rake/maven etc task. I use rake for my projects as it's much easier to maintain your build when it starts doing more than just running behat.